# Getting Last used cpu directly from linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I know the following steps.
"top" then "f" for fields and then "j" then enter.
Since top command is an interactive one, i'm not able implement in a script.
I need to get the P column of several processes and threads.

Found one more command "ps -o pid,psr,comm -p (pid)", but it's not working in the case of threads.

[click here for the image. Red marked one is the process id, while the thread id's not showing the cpu used info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMowV.jpg)

Comment: `ps -e -o pid,psr,comm | grep nginx`

Comment: or `ps -e -o pid,psr,comm -p 1234`  for pid 1234 select

Comment: Dear @beliy both are not working. Can you check the image also.

Comment: both variants work fine on my systems. Give more info about u system (OS, ps version etc.)

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit , procps version 3.2.8